# supersized: make sure a picture is not vertically cropped?

Tags: jquery, css, background, background-image, supersized

I am struggling with the following simple problem:

**Background:** I am using [Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) to display and rotate a bunch of background images on a page. In some of these pictures, the top part of the image is the most important element.

**Problem:** How do I keep supersized from vertically cropping my images? I prefer the image to be distorted and make sure its full height is visible.

**Solution that is not working:** From [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785918/supersized-how-to-stretch-images?rq=1), I got the idea of editing supersized.css from

```
#supersized img { width:auto; height:auto; position:relative; display:none; outline:none; border:none; }
```

to

```
#supersized img { width:auto; height:100%; position:relative; display:none; outline:none; border:none; }
```

but it didn't make a difference.